# jQuery Datatable's ajax request adds url parameter in test environment

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, datatables

I have built a web page that uses jQuery's Datatable to display a table. The data is fetched from the server. Before seeing the main page the user must login. This is implemented with Spring Security.

```
var table = $("#filesTable").DataTable({
        sAjaxSource: "/getAllRows",
...
```

This works on my local machine. The data is fetched and the table is populated. However, when I deploy the application in a test environment/server then the ajax request does not work. Chrome's inspector says that the request is sent to

```
/xgateUI/getAllRows?_=1598879359425
```

The number changes with each request.
Why does the ajax request for data have a different url with added parameter in the test environment? Does it have something to do with Spring Security? How can I fix this?

I'd appreciate any help or ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I had to replace

```
sAjaxSource: apiURL + "/getAllRows",´
```

with

```
ajax: {
            url:apiURL + "/getAllRows",
            cache: true
        },
```

See:

•  cache (default: true, false for dataType 'script' and 'jsonp')
Type: Boolean
If set to false, it will force requested pages not to be cached by the browser. Note: Setting cache to false will only work correctly with HEAD and GET requests. It works by appending "_={timestamp}" to the GET parameters. The parameter is not needed for other types of requests, except in IE8 when a POST is made to a URL that has already been requested by a GET.